# How can I print the return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**
How can I print the return index1,index2?  I try different ways but nothing was printed out.
**

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        nums = [2,7,11,15]
        target = 9
        hash_map = {}
        for index, value in enumerate(nums):
            hash_map[value] = index
        for index1, value in enumerate(nums):
            if target - value in hash_map:
                index2 = hash_map[target - value]
                if index1 != index2:
                    return [index1,index2]
```

Comment: What are the different ways you tried? Edit your question and include these attempts.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried.

Comment: If you have issues, better add it now or hold your peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        nums = [2,7,11,15]
        target = 9
        hash_map = {}
        for index, value in enumerate(nums):
            hash_map[value] = index
        for index1, value in enumerate(nums):
            if target - value in hash_map:
                index2 = hash_map[target - value]
                if index1 != index2:
                    return [index1,index2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Solution().twoSum(9, [2,7,11,15]))
```

I think what you are looking for is a `main` function in which you can use your function